# XMLSerializer keeps capitalizing items in collection

Tags: c#, collections, xml-serialization, wrapper, camelcasing

I need to export a collection of items in camel casing, for this I use a wrapper.

The class itself:

```
[XmlRoot("example")]
public class Example
{
    [XmlElement("exampleText")]
    public string ExampleText { get; set; }
}
```

This serializes fine:

```
<example>
    <exampleText>Some text</exampleText>
</example>
```

The wrapper:

```
[XmlRoot("examples")]
public class ExampleWrapper : ICollection<Example>
{
    [XmlElement("example")]
    public List<Example> innerList;

    //Implementation of ICollection using innerList
}
```

This however capitalizes the wrapped `Example`s for some reason, I tried to override it with `XmlElement` but this doesn't seem to have the desired effect:

```
<examples>
    <Example>
        <exampleText>Some text</exampleText>
    </Example>
    <Example>
        <exampleText>Another text</exampleText>
    </Example>
</examples>
```

Who can tell me what I am doing wrong or if there is an easier way?

Comment: You could always rename the `Example` type to `example` as a workround... If you can stand to break the conventions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `XmlSerializer` has built-in handling for collection types, meaning it it will ignore all your properties and fields (including `innerList`) if your type happens to implement `ICollection` and will just serialize it according to its own rules. However, you can customize the name of the element it uses for the collection items with the `XmlType` attribute (as opposed to the `XmlRoot` that you had used in your example):

```
[XmlType("example")]
public class Example
{
    [XmlElement("exampleText")]
    public string ExampleText { get; set; }
}
```

That will have the desired serialization.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx, specifically the answer to the question "Why aren't all properties of collection classes serialized?"

Comment: You are correct sir! Thanks. I've discarded the implementation of `ICollection` in favor of inheritance from `List`. It seems that `XmlRoot` isn't needed, am I right?

Comment: Correct, `XmlRoot` would only be necessary on `Example` if you were using that as the root of your serialized object graph.

Comment: This is working . uisng XmlType("") for the collection DataModel

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use just attributes to make this happen. You need to also use attribute overrides. Using you classes from above, I can use the `XmlTypeAttribute` to override the string representation of the class.

```
var wrapper = new ExampleWrapper();
var textes = new[] { "Hello, Curtis", "Good-bye, Curtis" };
foreach(var s in textes)
{
    wrapper.Add(new Example { ExampleText = s });
}

XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attributes = new XmlAttributes();
XmlTypeAttribute typeAttr = new XmlTypeAttribute();
typeAttr.TypeName = "example";
attributes.XmlType = typeAttr;
overrides.Add(typeof(Example), attributes);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExampleWrapper), overrides);
using(System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, wrapper);
    Console.WriteLine(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
}
```

This gives

```
<examples>
  <example>
    <exampleText>Hello, Curtis</exampleText>
  </example>
  <example>
    <exampleText>Good-bye, Curtis</exampleText>
  </example>
</examples>
```

which I believe you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[xmlType("DISPLAY_NAME")] is working for Inner object naming in xml Serialization in collections

```
 [XmlType("SUBSCRIPTION")]
    public class Subscription
    {
```